# Flask - return items to base.html

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I was wondering if it is possible to make a default route which will return objects or items to the base.html (which all the other pages inherit from)

something like this

```
@app.route(all)
def base():
    test = 'Avaible to all'
    return render_template('base.html', test=test)
```

and therefore in the base.html you can just call the desired object, test in this case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My base page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}

    <!-- same text to all pages -->
    {{ test }}
</body>
</html>
```

Of course if it is just a string I could just write it manually in the HTML - Base file, but hence I am asking is because I am going to implement sqlAlchemy and dynamic objects which will be changed over time in the back-end or database. 
It could for example be, Greetings (username) or today it is (the-time)

Comment: Check out the templating docs: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/ Maybe you're looking for a context processor?

Comment: That was indeed the correct answer! :) Feel free to post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [context processors](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors). Basically, they're a way to inject dictionary key/values into all templates in the app. For your example above:

```
@app.context_processor
def inject_test():
    return {'test': 'Available to all'}
```